# Can I automate PR creation and approval in command line?

Tags: git

We use azure pipeline to build and release. At the moment, we have sprint branch and master branch and we deploy from sprint and then merge to master after deployment succeeded.

What we would like to do is to deploy from Master branch(So merge from sprint to Master branch first and then merge).

Is it possible to use some script to create a PR (a pr between sprint and master branch), get the PR id and then approve the PR?

I find command `git request-pull`, which can create a PR in command line, but seems not easy to get the PR ID and approve it via command line.

I could just do a merge between sprint and master branch, but would like to do that as the last resort (ideally only allow master to change via PR).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, "PR" or "pull request" is not a concept that exists in Git. Are you referring to PRs on BitBucket, GitLab, GitHub, or some other host maybe?

Comment: That command "Generates a summary of pending changes". Any actual PR submission, approval, and completion process is either manual or handled by your git host.